# Possible ways to search Blockchain using ethereum-java api based on input/output parameters supplied as part of any transaction?

Tags: ethereumj

Although we know ethereum-java provides required api support which facilitate us to identify any block or transaction from Blockchain based on either block number or hash of transaction id. Do ethereum-java supports to execute search based on transactional input/output parameters (say my parameters are fixed like SL NO) to identify the history or say in which of the transaction/block its participated?
 Let me give an example of my need. Say I have 3 node running on one private network. Now each this three node has its own contract deployed, they are exchanging say one item which usually & uniquely identified based on its SL No. So the item baring the unique SL No many transfer from one node to another & the ownership of the same is changed. All this execution are part of transactions & hence part of some blocks. This successful executed transactions hold all the information’s like which SL No item transferred, from where to whom etc. Now do ethereum-java api provides any supports where by passing this input parameter say SL No we can identify which are the blocks or transactions where this has participated?

Comment: AFAIK the ethereum bloom filter only supports addresses, and topics (ie events). The input parameters are not part of the bloom filters. And the output is never recorded in the blockchain. I don't know the implementation of the java api. If you need filter by those fields, one option is that you store those fields in a separate databse for the transaction you are interested in.